# SIFT features with bagofFeatures

Tags: matlab, computer-vision, sift, matlab-cvst

In the Computer Vision System Toolbox the default features extraction is using SURF. How can use SIFT feature extraction using bagofFeatures class? Is there a Custom Feature Extractor available for the same?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure SIFT is built into Matlab. This might be because SIFT has a patent. There are some implementations by other people:

https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/50319-sift-feature-extreaction

[http://www.vlfeat.org/matlab/vl_sift.html](https://www.vlfeat.org/matlab/vl_sift.html)

You might need to wrap a call to one of these in a function that fits the required format of the `extractorFcn` argument of `bagOfFeatures`.